# Is it safe to nest macro invocations?

Tags: scala, macros, scala-2.10

I have been testing some nested macro invocations, and they worked as expected (...as expected by me!) For instance, supposing a ficticious *add* macro and the following expression:

```
add(1, add(2, 3))
```

Firstly the inner add is expanded (2 + 3) and secondly the outter one does its part (1 + (2 + 3)). I have seen that the outter macro does not receive any noise from the internal invocation -in the input expression- so the inner expansion seems totally transparent to it. Does this fact always hold (even with more complex macros and types)? Is it safe to do so?

Comment: I was unable to glean enough information from skimming to adequately answer your question, but you may be interested in this paper describing the Racket macro system: [Macros that Work Together: Compile-Time Bindings, Partial Expansion, and Deﬁnition Contexts](http://www.cs.utah.edu/plt/publications/jfp12-draft-fcdf.pdf)

Comment: I don't know well that specific paper, I've read only the conference version, but Scala's macro system is not entirely comparable-say, typechecking happens before macro expansion-although that's required to do name resolution and allow hygiene to be *added* by using reify. Don't be scared: Scala macros are not hygienic by default, but individual macros are if you only build ASTs to return via reify (which is somewhat similar to quasi-quotation, I still don't get the difference frankly).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Innermost macros are always expanded first (even if they are provided as by-name arguments).

Comment: I think the other part of the answer is (hopefully) that after expanding the inner macro, the result is typechecked before invoking the outer macro (otherwise, the output might not be fully typed/resolved).

Comment: Indeed, the expansion of the inner macros it is typechecked before being passed to the outer macro. Macro expansions are always typechecked right after they are returned from macro implementations.